404 error on the front end with the heyform app deployment
I am writing to request your assistance in troubleshooting the issue i am encountering while deploying heyform application to the windows server 2022. The issue is api throws 404 when trying to log in from the end.

server deployment is done

What could be the issue?
i was expecting successful log in as it works fine on my local
